# When passing char arrays as arguments, why isn't the null terminator included in the index?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

When you pass **char arrays** as arguments and try to find the length of the array, it returns the length without the null operator?

For example, if I passed `charArray[4] = "aaa"` and found the length of this using `strlen`, the returned value would be 3. Why is this so?

More detailed example below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    void function(char[]);

    char charArray[4] = "aaa";
    function(charArray);

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}

void function (char *array)
{
    size_t index = 0;
    index = strlen(array);

    std::cout << index; // prints value: 3
}
```

Comment: Because `man strlen`: strlen() function calculates the length of the string s, *excluding the terminating null byte*.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `char` arrays with the behavior of string literals, c-style strings respectively.

`strlen()` operates on NUL terminated character arrays and doesn't count the terminating `\0` character [by definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen):

> 1. Returns the length of the given null-terminated byte string, that is, the number of characters in a character array whose first element is pointed to by str up to and not including the first null character.
>      The behavior is undefined if str is not a pointer to a null-terminated byte string.

---

To get the size of an array use `sizeof()` like so:

```
char arr[4] = "abc";
cout << sizeof(arr) << endl;
```

You should note that the above sample will not give you correct results, as soon the array is decayed to a pointer that is passed to a function:

```
char arr[4] = "abc";

void func(char* arr)
{
    cout << sizeof(arr) << endl; // Prints the size of the pointer variable itself
}
```

Such functions need to get the array size from an extra parameter:

```
void func(char* arr, size_t arrsize)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Careful with this one.   If that array is passed to a function as an argument, it is passed as a pointer to the first element of the array.   `sizeof(array)` inside the function will therefore give the size of the pointer, not the original size of the array.

Comment: I see now. My lecturer said at one point that you can basically think of character arrays as strings. I suppose that is where I got confused. Thank you!

Comment: @SebastianKing: It's the "basically" that's important ;)

Comment: Thank you Peter. I assume that would therefore return a value of 1?

Comment: `sizeof(pointer)` is most likely 4 or 8, depending on the operating system.

Comment: I was merely correcting OP that size of a pointer is definitely not 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of the null as more of an implementation detail, that might help.

If you know std::string at all, you want length() to return the actual length.  Every other major language has a string of some sort, and they all have a function to get the length.

Also, you really want strlen(a+b) == strlen(a) + strlen(b), otherwise a lot of operations get a bit more complicated. You only want to count a null once. When you strcat.

Answer (score -1):

strlen does not return the length with the null character because the null character determines where the C string ends in memory.

(ie it is not part of the string, it tells the runtime where the string ends).

See: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28computer_science%29#Null-terminated
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string